# datetimepicker startDate endDate control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datepicker, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

The start date can not be later than the end date. This is working.

But, when the end date is first selected, the start date can be selected to a later date. I don't want this.

How can I control this?

We use asp.Net / Webform. 
I could not paste the c # code here correctly. Snipped is not working properly because of this.

```js
$('#<%=dtEduStart.ClientID%>').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd.M.yyyy',
  weekStart: 1,
  todayBtn: 0,
  autoclose: 1,
  todayHighlight: 1,
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  forceParse: 0,
  todayBtn: 1,
  endDate: '+0d',
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  $('#<%=dtEduFinish.ClientID%>').datetimepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
});

$('#<%=dtEduFinish.ClientID%>').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd.M.yyyy',
  weekStart: 1,
  todayBtn: 0,
  autoclose: 1,
  todayHighlight: 1,
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  forceParse: 0,
  todayBtn: 1,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Starting Date<span class="red bolder">*</span></label>
  <div id='divEduStart' runat="server">
    <div class="input-group date form_date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
      <input id="dtEduStart" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control dtpStart" data-placeholder="Starting Date" readonly /></div>
    <span id="spnEduStart" runat="server"></span></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Graduation Date<span class="red bolder">*</span></label>
  <div id="divEduFinish" runat="server">
    <div class="input-group date form_date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
      <input id="dtEduFinish" runat="server" type="text" data-placeholder="Graduation Date" class="form-control dtpEnd" readonly /></div>
  </div>
  <span id="spnEduFinish" runat="server"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code example I don't see any handling for the event change of the second datapicker, you need to handle that event too for your purpose.
I raccomand you to use the jQuery event "dp.change" for the datapicker, like this:

```
  $('#dtEduStart').on('dp.change', function(e) {    
    $('#dtEduFinish').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });
  $('#dtEduFinish').on('dp.change', function(ev) {
    $('#dtEduStart').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(ev.date);
  });
```

I've made an [example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/dbt8yc6L/) to clarify.

Comment: But this time, when I select the endDate as an future date, I can enter the startDate as a later date than today.
Regardless, the startDate cannot be a date later than today.

How to do this?

Comment: you can do that by adding a minDate when you create the datepicker like this: 
$('#dtEduStart').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD.M.YYYY',
    minDate: moment()
  });

Comment: I've update my fiddle with this change. To avoid errors, I've added a minDate also to 'dtEduFinish' with the tomorrow date. https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/dbt8yc6L/4/

Comment: Hi @Cansu Arı if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.